# How can I precompile jade.php templates?

Tags: php, wordpress, pug, npm

I've fallen in love with Jade, and can't bear to se  any more, but now I have a WordPress theme to design..

So.. I use [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/), and it handles jade just fine - can I somehow get it to use [jade.php](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php) instead of the node module? (I couldn't find any packages which mentioned php when i searched `npm find jade | grep php`)

Could this be accomplished with a grunt watch task?

I'd prefer not to install jade.php in the theme and have it run there.

---

Also, I'm aware that I can escape the php..

```
#sidebar1.sidebar.fourcol.last.clearfix(role="complementary")

    | <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ) ) : ?>
    |   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
    | <?php else : ?>

    // This content shows up if there are no widgets defined in the backend.

    .alert.alert-help
        p <?php _e( 'Please activate some Widgets.', 'bonestheme' );  ?>

    | <?php endif; ?>
```

But I'd love to use jade conditionals.. is that greedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ajschlosser/wordpress-jade-template is great for regular wordpress. I'm more of a bootstrap person so I prefer the Bootstrap verison at https://github.com/ajschlosser/wordpress-jade-bootstrap-template which also relies on Sass for some reason (even though Bootstrap is Less oriented) so I forked it and made it more Less biased. https://github.com/Xedecimal/wordpress-jade-bootstrap-template in case you don't want to do it yourself, pretty easy though.

Answer (score 0):

I just fond on Github a projet named grunt-jade, and they talk about the watch mode :
https://github.com/phated/grunt-jade

I think that would help you.